# gdal_grid, how to set pixel size?

Tags: gdal, gdal-grid

I'm using `gdal_grid` to convert a shapefile with points and I would like to set the pixel size of the output. I've only found the `-outsize` flag that lets me set the size of the output raster, but I would prefer to just say that I want 2 x 2 m pixels and let the tool figure out the size of the output raster.

With `gdal_rasterize` you can set the `-tr` flag, but that tool won't do interpolation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**GDAL version <3.2**

To set the pixel size in [`gdal_grid`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html), you have to play with the following options:

> **-txe xmin xmax:**
>
> ```
> Set georeferenced X extents of output file to be created.
> ```
>
> **-tye ymin ymax:**
>
> ```
> Set georeferenced Y extents of output file to be created.
> ```
>
> **-outsize xsize ysize:**
>
> ```
> Set the size of the output file in pixels and lines.
> ```

because:

```
xcellsize = (xmax - xmin) / xsize
ycellsize = (ymax - ymin) / ysize
```

---

***New in GDAL version 3.2.***

> **-tr xres yres**
>
> ```
> Set output file resolution (in target georeferenced units). Note that -tr just works in combination with a valid input from -txe and -tye
> ```